# 理由的理: specify a character by context

Tags: terminology

This method is often used to clarify which exact character of a certain pronunciation is meant, for example when saying one's name:

> 我叫王立：不是力量的力，是成立的立。

It is used so frequently that I assume there is a word for it (like a historical method to describe a character's pronunciation was called [*fanqie* 反切](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie)).

What is this method called?

Comment: I just call it's an explanation.

Comment: It's like spelling an English name over the phone: "B, as in beta". I'd just say it's the method of: "use it in a word"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it **釐清** (to clarify)

> 釐清 這個 'li' 是 理由的理, 不是 里程的里
>
> to clarify this 'li'  is 理 for 理由, not 里 for 里程

or

**闡明** (to clarify )

> 闡明 這個 'li' 是理由的理, 不是 里程的里
>
> to clarify this 'li' is 理 for 理由, not 里 for 里程

神秘德里克 wrote:

> *提问人问专门的词，这两个词也不是说专门表示这件事情。应该是没有什么专门的词专门表达这件事情。*

I agree there is no specific term for 'specify a character by context' .

'specify a character by context' is an act of '釐清' or '闡明' a character

> "你叫 Huáng Yuán? 請問是那一個 Yuán?" (Your name is Huáng Yuán? May I ask which yuán is that?)

"To clarify (釐清/闡明) which 'Yuán' is in his name, 黃源 said: 'it is the 源 in 水源"

Comment: 提问人问专门的词，这两个词也不是说专门表示这件事情。可能是没有什么专门的词专门表达这件事情吧。